# Can a JavaScript variable be true N times and then false?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to have a JavaScript variable that, when used by other code, works as a boolean (a single bit of memory) but has an internal state so that it is true the first N times that the value is read, and then false?

In other words, is it possible to define `trueNTimes` so that the following code prints `yes` 3 times and then prints `no` 2 times?

```js
let true3times = trueNTimes(3);
for (let i = 5; i; --i)
    if (true3times) console.log('yes');
    else console.log('no');
```

As as a side note, it can be done in C++ (by defining `struct TrueNTimes` with `operator bool`) like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
struct TrueNTimes {
    TrueNTimes(uint const N) : n(N) {}
    operator bool() {
        if (n) {
            --n; 
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
private:
    uint n;
};

int main() {
    TrueNTimes true3times(3);
    for (uint i = 5; i; --i)
        if (true3times) std::cout << "yes\n";
        else std::cout << "no\n";
}
```

The C++ compiler finds a variable of type `struct TrueNTimes` where a `bool` is needed and will therefore use the provided `TrueNTimes::operator bool`.

Comment: You could write a comparable function in JavaScript to the C++ you showed, yes. When you attempted to write this function, where did you get stuck?

Comment: at operator bool

Comment: So show the code you came up with, clearly explain what you wanted/expected that code to do (*don't* assume we can accurately read your intent from the C++ you posted), and explain how it failed to meet your expectations. Please, read "*[ask]*" (along with "*[mcve]*").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in JavaScript you would define `valueOf`:

```js
function trueNTimes(n) {
    return {
        valueOf() {
            if (n) {
                --n; 
                return true;
            } else 
                return false;
        }
    }
};

let true3times = trueNTimes(3);
console.log(true3times + ' ' + true3times + ' ' + true3times + ' ' + true3times + ' ' + true3times);
```

As in JavaScript objects are always truthy, you need to really compare this variable in order to trigger the `valueOf` algorithm:

```js
function trueNTimes(n) {
    return {
        valueOf() {
            if (n) {
                --n; 
                return true;
            } else 
                return false;
        }
    }
};

let true3times = trueNTimes(3);
for (let i = 5; i; --i)
    if (true3times == true) console.log('yes');
    else console.log('no');
```

Comment: See addition to answer.

Comment: Thanks. I assume that this is the closest we can get in JavaScript.